# std::map<struct,struct>::find is not finding a match, but if i loop thru begin() to end() i see the match right there

Tags: c++, string, dictionary, struct, find

```
struct chainout {
    LONG cl;
    std::string cs;
    bool operator<(const chainout&o)const {
      return cl < o.cl || cs < o.cs;
    }
  } ;
  struct chainin{
    std::string tm;
    std::string tdi;
    short mss;
    LONG pinid;
    bool operator<(const chainin&o)const {
      return  mss < o.mss || pinid < o.pinid || tm<o.tm; //no tdi right now it's always empty
    }
  };
  std::map   <chainin,chainout> chainmap;
  std::map<chainin,chainout>::iterator it;
  chainin ci;
  chainout co;


 string FADEDevicePinInfo::getNetAtPinIdTmTidMss (const LONG p,const string tm, const string tid,const LONG mss){

  ci.tm=tm;
//  ci.tdi=tid;
  ci.tdi="";
  ci.mss=(short)mss;
  ci.pinid=p;
  for (it=chainmap.begin();it!=chainmap.end();it++){
    if(it->first.pinid==ci.pinid && it->first.tm==ci.tm&&it->first.mss==ci.mss && it->first.tdi==ci.tdi){
      cout << "BDEBUG: found p["; cout<<it->first.pinid; cout<<"] tm["; cout<<it->first.tm.c_str();cout<<"] mss[";cout<<it->first.mss;cout<<"] : ";cout<<it->second.chainSignal.c_str();cout<<endl;
    }
  }
  it=chainmap.find(ci);
  if(it == chainmap.end()){
    MSG(SEV_T,("no pin data found for pin[%ld]/tm[%s]/tdi[%s]/mss[%ld]",ci.pinid,ci.tm.c_str(),ci.tdi.c_str(),ci.mss));
  }
  return it->second.cs;
}
```

This is both printing the successfully found line, and then throwing the sev_t error due to map::find not returning a match.  what did i do wrong?

I added print statements thruout the < function, but it seems to be ordering the map correctly, and when i do the lookup, it seems to find the correct mss/pinid, but then only sees one tm, which is the wrong tm.

Comment: Pop quiz: you have to `chainout`s, one has `cl=3`, and `cs="B"`, and the other one has `cl=4` and `cs="A"`. Which one is less than the other one? Your `<` will conclude that either one of them is less than the other one. As Mr. Spock would say: this is not logical. This `<` operator fails to implement strict weak ordering, and this results in undefined behavior and [demons flying out of your nose](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/nasal_demon), as you've observed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As noted in comments, you have a bad comparison operator. If you don't know what order the objects should be sorted in, then neither does std::map or any other sorted container.

When you have multiple things to compare, consider deciding which is most important, and use std::tie to compare them, as demonstrated here:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

struct chainout {
    int cl;
    std::string cs;
    bool operator<(const chainout&o)const {
        return std::tie(cl, cs) < std::tie(o.cl, o.cs);
    }
};

int main(){
    chainout a{ 1, "b" };
    chainout b{ 2, "a" };
    std::cout << (a < b) << std::endl;
    std::cout << (b < a) << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The `operator<` for both of your `struct`s are implemented incorrectly.

`std::map` requires key comparisons to use [**Strict Weak Ordering**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_ordering#Strict_weak_orderings).  That means when your structs want to compare multiple fields, they need to compare later fields *only* when earlier fields compare *equal*.  But you are not checking for that condition.  You are returning `true` if *any* field in one instance compares less-than the corresponding field in the other instance, regardless of the equality (or lack of) in the other fields.  So you are breaking SWO, which causes *undefined behavior* in `std::map`'s lookups.

Try this instead:

```cpp
struct chainout {
    LONG cl;
    std::string cs;
    bool operator<(const chainout &o) const {
        /*
        if (cl < o.cl) return true;
        if (cl == o.cl) return (cs < o.cs);
        return false;
        */
        return (cl < o.cl) || ((cl == o.cl) && (cs < o.cs));
    }
};

struct chainin{
    std::string tm;
    std::string tdi;
    short mss;
    LONG pinid;
    bool operator<(const chainin &o) const {
        if (mss < o.mss) return true;
        if (mss == o.mss) {
            if (pinid < o.pinid) return true;
            if (pinid == o.pinid) return (tm < o.tm);
        }
        return false;
    }
};
```

An easier way to implement this is to use [`std::tie()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie) instead, which has its own `operator<` to handle this for you, eg:

```cpp
struct chainout {
    LONG cl;
    std::string cs;
    bool operator<(const chainout &o) const {
        return std::tie(cl, cs) < std::tie(o.cl, o.cs);
    }
};

struct chainin{
    std::string tm;
    std::string tdi;
    short mss;
    LONG pinid;
    bool operator<(const chainin &o) const {
        return std::tie(mss, pinid, tm) < std::tie(o.mss, o.pinid, o.tm);
    }
};
```

Either way, then `std::map::find()` should work as expected, eg:

```cpp
std::map<chainin, chainout> chainmap;

string FADEDevicePinInfo::getNetAtPinIdTmTidMss (const LONG p, const string tm, const string tid, const LONG mss)
{
    chainin ci;
    ci.tm = tm;
    //ci.tdi = tid;
    ci.tdi = "";
    ci.mss = (short) mss;
    ci.pinid = p;

    std::map<chainin, chainout>::iterator it = chainmap.find(ci);
    if (it != chainmap.end()) {
        cout << "BDEBUG: found"
             << " p[" << it->first.pinid << "]"
             << " tm[" << it->first.tm << "]"
             << " mss[" << it->first.mss << "]"
             << " : " << it->second.cs
             << endl;
    }
}
```